# HashMap append in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to update the hashmap in an array , but not able to do so.

```
def incrementCount(combiners: Array[Combiner], row: Row): Array[Combiner] = {
   val tempMapTypes = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, (String, Array[String])]
   for (i <- 0 until row.length) {
       val array = getMyType(row(i), tempMapTypes)
       for (elem <- tempMapTypes) {
         combiners(i).mapTypes.update(elem._1,elem._2) <<<< this update doesnt work for me, always mapTypes is empty
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the Combiner class

```
case class Combiner(<other variables>, mapTypes: mutable.HashMap[String, (String, Array[String])])
         combiners
         }
```

And this is how, it got initialized in another method...

```
val mapTypes = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, (String, Array[String])]
combiners += new Combiner(....,mapTypes)
```

As mentioned above, after the initialization of this case class, how do I append mapTypes, the above update code doesnt seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your update code you can to define a `++=` method on `Combiner` :

```
class Combiner(..., mapTypes: mutable.HashMap[String, (String, Array[String])]) {

  ...

  def ++=(otherMapTypes: mutable.HashMap[String, (String, Array[String])]): Unit = 
    this.mapTypes ++= otherMapTypes

}
```

Then you can do the following :

```
for(i <- row.length) {
  combiners(i) ++= tempMapTypes
}
```